# Access Date Expression to SQL Crystal Reports Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

In access the formula is and functions properly:

```
Test_2: Test_2: IIf(Max([Material_Trans_Date]) Is Null,#7/1/2011#,Max([Material_Trans_Date]))
```

When trying to recreate in SQL Server () it errors on the `'#'` and `"#"`.

How can I express the `#7/1/2011#` in SQL for Crystal Reports properly?

I have tried `'7-01-2011'` and the results are always `Blank/Null` and `7-01-2011` doesn't show at all.

Answer (score 0):

SQL SERver needs dates in another format

```
SELECT IIf(Max([Material_Trans_Date]) Is Null,'20110701',Max([Material_Trans_Date]))

SELECT IIf(Max([Material_Trans_Date]) Is Null,'2011-07-01',Max([Material_Trans_Date]))
```

```
CREATE TABLE Material_Req(Material_Req int, Material_Trans_Date date, Material int)
```

```
INSERT INTO Material_Req VALUEs(1,NULL,1)
```

```
CREATE tABLe Material_Trans (Material_Req int,Tran_Type varchar(100))
```

```
INSERT INTO Material_Trans VALUEs (1,'Ätest')
```

```
SELECT 
Material_Req.Material
, IIf(Max([Material_Trans_Date]) Is Null,'2023-11-01',Max([Material_Trans_Date])) AS Test_2 
FROM Material_Req LEFT JOIN Material_Trans ON Material_Req.Material_Req = Material_Trans.Material_Req 
WHERE (((Material_Trans.Tran_Type)<>'Adjustment')) 
GROUP BY Material_Req.Material;
```

| Material | Test_2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-11-01 |

```
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KJtTiBxe)

Comment: Thanks for the kind reply. I added that aspect to the code and still receive no results. Complete code ...SELECT Material_Req.Material, IIf(Max([Material_Trans_Date]) Is Null,#7/1/2011#,Max([Material_Trans_Date])) AS Test_2
FROM Material_Req LEFT JOIN Material_Trans ON Material_Req.Material_Req = Material_Trans.Material_Req
WHERE (((Material_Trans.Tran_Type)<>"Adjustment"))
GROUP BY Material_Req.Material;

Comment: a  i have a fiddle to demonstrate hat it works as inetnded